# C# configuration reads yaml incorrect

Tags: c#, configuration, yaml

I use .net core 3.1, linux, docker.

When i have a json config, i can write something like that:

json:

```
{ "SomeSection": {...} }
```

c# :

```
// Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Configuration from DI

var section = Configuration.GetSection("SomeSection");
Console.WriteLine(section.Value); // returns "null"

var children = section.GetChildren().ToArray();
foreach (var child in children) Console.Writeline(child.Value); // returns values from json
```

But when i switched to yaml, i started to have this situation:

yaml:

```
SomeSection:
  SomeKey: SomeValue
```

c# :

```
// Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Configuration from DI

var section = Configuration.GetSection("SomeSection");
Console.WriteLine(section.Value); // returns "map[SomeKey:SomeValue]"

var children = section.GetChildren().ToArray(); // empty array
```

And ok - new format equals new rules to read that format. But even YamlDotNET can't parse string `map[SomeKey:SomeValue]`. What do i do wrong?

Tried to write yaml like

```
SomeSection:{SomeKey: SomeValue}
```

but also get `map[...]`

Tried to make something like

```
SomeSection:
  Level1:
    Level2:
      SomeKey: SomeValue
```

And it also seems like `map[Level1:map[Level2:map[SomeKey:SomeValue]]]`

Comment: Never used yaml here and not sure how the naming of the Configuration interface maps to yaml but i would consider your "SomeSection" as a SectionGroup and not a Section. So try GetSectionGroup instead of GetSection.

Comment: @Ralf strange... i have only method `GetSection` and extension method `GetRequiredSection`. Maybe `GetSectionGroup ` appeared only in in .net 6+ ?..

Comment: Or i just mixed up the different Configuration Systems in the Framework . You seem to be looking at "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" while i had "System.Configuration" in mind. Sorry.